Why do the last two Hebrew words of 2 Kings 17:31 WLC have no "niqqud" (vowel dotting)?
So, my question is simple: why are there no vowel dots in the last two words in Masoretic Text in this line?
2 Kings 17:31 KJV

And the Avites made Nibhaz and Tartak, and the Sepharvites burnt their children in fire to Adrammelech and Anammelech, the gods of Sepharvaim.

2 Kings 17:31 WLC

וְהָעַוִּים עָשׂוּ נִבְחַז וְאֶת־תַּרְתָּק וְהַסְפַרְוִים שֹׂרְפִים אֶת־בְּנֵיהֶם בָּאֵשׁ לְאַדְרַמֶּלֶךְ וַעֲנַמֶּלֶךְ אלה ספרים

(both quotes taken from the Blue Letter Bible site)
My guess is that it is a later editorial note or something like that. I did not find anything that answered it. Also, for me, it seems that the word, which translated as "the gods", was not used here in a common way.

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

The Biblia Hebraica Stuttgartensia has vowel points on these two words; so does the BFS Hebrew Bible of 1965.

@Dottard. But the question remains, why does ב מְלָכִים (WLC) have no points on the last two words?

Here is the text of the last three words of 2 kings 17:31 as it appears in all six of the printed editions (on my shelf) of the Hebrew Bible, including Biblia Hebraica Stuttgartensia (BHS):

וַֽעֲנַמֶּ֖לֶךְ אֱלֹהֵ֥ סְפַרְוָֽיִם׃ = and Anammelech, gods of
Sepharites

Note that the last two words are pointed.  However, BHS has a marginal note (as distinct from the foot notes of BHS) about the last two words which provides an alternate reading of almost the same two words but the word "gods" become singular - this marginal reading is from the time of the Masoretes and is unpointed Hebrew.
Now, it appears that the Blue Letter Bible site (as quoted by the OP) uses the alternate reading.  On the other hand, BibleHub site  https://biblehub.com/multi/2_kings/17-31.htm  provides both but using different brackets.  Thus we read in BibleHub for the last three words:
(וַֽעֲנַמֶּ֖לֶךְ [אֱלֹהַּ כ] (אֱלֹהֵ֥י ק) [סְפַרִים כ] (סְפַרְוָֽיִם׃ ק

Note: BHS includes the Masoretic notes in the margin on the left or right (depending on the edition) - the footnotes have alternate readings in other MSS that differ from the Leningrad codex.

Still both the Blue Letter Bible and the BibleHub sites anchor the word to Strong's H433, that does not align with any variant in brackets. First is H426 and second is H430. But that is my next question, and now I'm not sure yet how to put it correctly as a new one.

As @Dottard pointed in comments, there are vowel signs in the Biblia Hebraica Stuttgartensia; in 2Regum 17:31, page 654 of the BHS e-copy on archive.org.
It looks like that:

There is also a note (b) placed on the same page for the first word, but for a very beginner like me, it is almost non-parsable enigma. Only obvious thing is that there are two variants of word inscription based on two somethings, I marked them with red underscore, and the first one is a common plural, constructive form of 'elohim', while the second one is single absolute form of word, which is used mostly in Ezra and Daniel. Here they are:

I have tried to read the SIGLA ET COMPENDIA APPARATUUM on page 10, but only thing which was kind of a clear is the letter Q, which stands for Codex Marchalianus, even though it is dated by VI century, according to wikipedia it does not include the book of Kings, and it is written in Greek. Only kind of a clear, because I can only guess how it was used for vowels clarification. I can imagine only something sanely obvious like "it was plural here in Greek, — common plural in other manuscripts is constructive form of 'elohim', so let it be such in Hebrew". With a lot of cross-checks, and other sense-chaining stuff.
Partly, — all said answers my question, and makes my initial guess, at least, reasonable. What stays unclear are these:
— Why did BHS authors choose not first nor second variant of word inscription, placed in (b)? It is understandable why not second, but why not first one?
— Why did WLC authors not pick common constructive plural for "the gods", and did place unfinished form, that is commonly used for singular absolute?
— Two enigmatic markers of word inscription variants, where they came from.
— Why did James Strong marked this word in this place not as H430 nor as H426, but as H433, which differs from both even more?
P.S. Please, point on my wrong assumptions if there are any, I am very beginner of Hebrew grammar and translation nuances of the Bible.
UPD:
@Dottard have just posted a partial answer on third subquestion.
Maybe it is reasonable to combine, rethink, and create new topic, but for now I can only leave this as a draft here.

You need to look in the margin (not the footnotes) of BHS as per my answer.

@Dottard Oh, I see, Mm, Mp, Mg markers, thank you.
